# What's the difference between instantiateInitialViewController and instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:?

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard

If I have a storyboard whose viewcontroller has been tagged. then What's the difference between these 2 APIs?

What I want to know is whether there is some difference on returned object. are they exactly same or one of them will initialize more things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **instantiateInitialViewController:** to instatiate the default view (initial), this is something you wouldn't do programmatically usually

Use **instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:** when you would like a `ViewController` And attach a view from the `storyboard` (storyboard Id (Identifier))

Comment: Does that mean If there are several viewcontroller in one storyboard file, then instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier can load non-default view controller. But If there is only one viewcontroller in the storyboard file, then there is no difference?

Comment: You have many `viewControllers` on your storyboard. But you must have the initial one , when the app launches it will look for that one, in other word the main entry point