# Branch Universal Link not working

Tags: ios, deep-linking, branch.io, ios-universal-links

I am using Branch.io to implement Universal Links in my app. Every time I copy and paste a Universal Link (from my app) to Notes I click on 'OPEN IN (APP)' and it redirects me to the wrong view controller. It directs me to the the main view controller that the user sees when they first open the app. Something must be wrong with my Deep Link Routing in my **AppDelegate.m** file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

Branch *branch = [Branch getInstance];

WebDeepLinkViewController *WebDeepLinkViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateInitialViewController];
[branch registerDeepLinkController:WebDeepLinkViewController forKey:@"Article"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Alex from Branch.io here:

It looks like you are calling `instantiateInitialViewController`. As its name implies, [this loads the main view controller that the user sees when they first open the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234472/whats-the-difference-between-instantiateinitialviewcontroller-and-instantiatevi). You want `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`

Also, you might be missing a line, unless you simply didn't include it in the snippet:

```
[branch initSessionWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions automaticallyDisplayDeepLinkController:YES];
```

The corrected version would look like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

Branch *branch = [Branch getInstance];

WebDeepLinkViewController *WebDeepLinkViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DeepLinkingController"];

[branch registerDeepLinkController:WebDeepLinkViewController forKey:@"Article"];
[branch initSessionWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions automaticallyDisplayDeepLinkController:YES];
```

*(`DeepLinkingController` is the Storyboard ID. If you don't know how to set this, you can find instructions [here](http://sketchytech.blogspot.com/2012/11/instantiate-view-controller-using.html))*

Comment: Okay, after I corrected the code, I tested it & the universal link sent me to the app, accept the entire screen turned white. It seems when I add `[branch initSessionWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions automaticallyDisplayDeepLinkController:YES];` the app's view controller turns completely white. What can possibly be wrong?

Comment: Hard to tell... Could you share your full AppDelegate and view controller code? If you don't want to post that here, feel free to [submit a ticket](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) for the Branch Integrations Team

Comment: Discovered the problem. With the corrected code the Universal Link took me to the correct view controller. However, The view controller elements are missing, which included a button & a custom web view. The only elements that are correct is an image and a Label. How do I keep these elements?

Comment: I assume its under the BranchUniversalObject 'addMetadataKey' Not too sure.

Comment: Hard to tell. Can you include the items requested previously? That will help